# UBUNTU 22.04.3 it does not recognize the onboard audio

Tags: sound

I have Ubuntu 22.04.3 but it does not recognize the onboard audio of the motherboard A520M S2H (GIGABYTE).
Actually I had another ASUS motherboard (A320M-K-BR) where I had installed Ubuntu 22.04.3 but also in that case the onboard audio didn't work.

If I go to `Settings` the Sound Icon, appears in the output device Box: "Fisticia Output".

Is there any solution for this?

Thank you!

Comment: Attach the output of this command: `journalctl -k | grep -Ei "ALSA|HDA|sof[-]|HDMI|snd[_-]|sound|hda.codec|hda.intel"`

Comment: nothing happened

Comment: I executed the given command but nothing happened!!

Comment: Try Ubuntu 23.10. It should support more recent hardware than 22.04

Comment: Please attach more system info: `sudo apt install inxi` and then `inxi -Fxxzc0` in terminal

Comment: Look at your system startup log (watch your kernel discover the hardware) with the terminal command `sudo journalctl  -b 0`. Read `man journalctl`.